# Getting gradient thresholds OpenLayers heatmap?

Tags: openlayers, javascript, heat-map

I develop an application that displays results of the measurements of pollutants in snow. Due to large size of the area (lake Baikal), it is difficult to take samples everywhere, so I was asked to interpolate the results using Empirical Bayesian Kriging.

By setting blur and radius of the points on the heatmap, I can show the result of the interpolation, see the picture below[image: Snow measurements results interpolation]

Blue markers are points where samples were taken.

The problem is that, for the blue markers I can show a popover with the measurement result, and even for the points with the interpolated data I probably can show popover too. But for the usability, I want to add the legend.

Heatmap allows to obtain the gradient colors via `getGradient()` method, returning something like this `['#00f', '#0ff', '#0f0', '#ff0', '#f00']`. But can I get the threshold values for this gradient? Or I need to add multiple layers manually in order to have such values?

```
function drawHeatmap(type = null) {
        const data = {
            type: 'FeatureCollection',
            features: []
        };

        max_weight = 0;
        min_weight = 1000 * 1000 * 1000;

        if (type !== null && String(type) !== '0') {
            measurements.forEach(measurement => {
                let val = measurement[type];

                if (val < 0) {
                    val = 0;
                }

                if (max_weight < val) {
                    max_weight = val;
                }

                if (min_weight > val) {
                    min_weight = val;
                }

                data.features.push({
                    type: "Feature",
                    geometry: {
                        type: "Point",
                        coordinates: [measurement.point.longitude, measurement.point.latitude],
                    },
                    properties: {
                        title: measurement.point.name,
                        name: measurement.point.name,
                        weight: val
                    }
                });
            });


            let calc_ptr = 0;
            calculated_data.forEach(calculation => {
                if (typeof calculation.values[type] !== 'undefined') {
                    let val = calculation.values[type];

                    if (val < 0) {
                        val = 0;
                    }

                    if (max_weight < val) {
                        max_weight = val;
                    }

                    if (min_weight > val) {
                        min_weight = val;
                    }

                    data.features.push({
                        type: "Feature",
                        geometry: {
                            type: "Point",
                            coordinates: [calculation.longitude, calculation.latitude],
                        },
                        properties: {
                            weight: val
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        if (typeof heatmap !== 'undefined') {
            myMap.removeLayer(heatmap);
        }

        const heatFeature = new VectorSource({
            features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(data, {
                dataProjection: "EPSG:4326",
                featureProjection: "EPSG:3857"
            })
        });

        heatmap = new HeatmapLayer({
            title: "HeatMap",
            source: heatFeature,
            blur: current_heatmap_blur,
            radius: current_heatmap_radius,
            weight: function (feature) {
                return (feature['values_']['weight'] - min_weight) / (max_weight - min_weight);
            }
        });

        myMap.addLayer(heatmap);
    }
```

Comment: @TomazicM code added

Comment: Calculating distinct threshold values shouldn't be difficult. Since `weight` values range from 0 to 1 and for example default `gradient` has 5 values, thresholds for this case are at 0.2 interval.

Comment: @TomazicM thanks, it works