# Heatmap in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, heat-map

Each discrete data point is classified into increasing levels of severity: '1' (green), '2' (blue), and '3' (red).

I would like to do something like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/446444/getting-gradient-thresholds-openlayers-heatmap) example. I am trying to be able to distinguish each point. I tried changing the Heatmap gradient and the weight depending on the severity of the point, but Red is particularly dominant.

The code I have is below:

```
if (mapRef.current && tempData && tempData.length > 0) {
  // find the min, max and mean temperature values
  const tempValues = tempData?.map((point) => point.icing_degree_code);
  const tempMax = Math.max(...tempValues);
  const tempMin = Math.min(...tempValues);
  const tempMean =
    tempValues.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val) / tempValues.length;

  const heatmapSource = new VectorSource({
    features:
      tempData &&
      tempData
        .map((point) => {
          if (point && point.Long && point.Lat) {
            // normalize weight value
            const weight = 
              (point.icing_degree_code - tempMin) / (tempMax - tempMin);

              

             
            return new ol.Feature({
              geometry: new Point(fromLonLat([point.Long, point.Lat])),
              weight: weight,
            });
          }
        })
        .filter(Boolean),
  });

  // create the heatmap layer with the dynamic gradient
  const blur = 0;
  const radius = 10;
  // create the heatmap layer with the dynamic gradient
  //
  //
  const colorGradient = [
    "rgba(0, 255, 0, 1.0)",
    "rgba(255, 165, 0, 1.0)",
    "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)",
  ];


  if (!heatmapLayer) {
    heatmapLayer = new Heatmap({
      source: heatmapSource,
      blur: blur,
      radius: radius,
      opacity: 0.5,
      gradient: colorGradient,
    });
    map.addLayer(heatmapLayer);
  } else {
    heatmapLayer.setSource(heatmapSource);
  }
}

 }, [tempData]);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: There can be two reasons why red color prevails: (1) That's the nature of the data (2) In your color gradient red color prevails, so change the gradient.